# Migrating Oracle Secure Global Desktop on Azure

Tags: oracle, azure, migration

We have to migrate the Oracle Secure Global Desktop application on Azure cloud.

So, My question is as below-

1. Is it possible to migrate above application on Azure cloud ?
2. If we plan to migrate it what thing I have to take care?

Regards,
Abhi

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect Oracle Secure Global Desktop with Azure cloud as the oracle have partnered with Microsoft with the private connectivity by enabling VPN access.

> For private access from your data center to  Oracle Cloud, use either  Oracle Cloud Infrastructure FastConnect  or IPSec VPN. Similarly, for private traffic from your data center to  Microsoft Azure, use  ExpressRoute  or VPN.
> For cross-cloud networking between  Oracle Cloud  and  Microsoft Azure, set up a connection between a FastConnect circuit in  Oracle Cloud  and an  ExpressRoute  circuit in  Microsoft Azure.

you can connect through Microsoft Azure Virtual Network and Express Route

Here is the [document](https://docs.oracle.com/en/solutions/learn-azure-oci-interconnect/index.html#GUID-A1D8663A-52D9-47C1-A246-CAEF952F1653) with complete information.

Comment: Here, I am not looking forward to connect Oracle Cloud. I am trying to achieve migration by using Azure Cloud and user will connect from on -premise. For this application.